# Are these sentence shortenings grammatically correct and do they make sense?

Tags: grammar

For vocabulary study, I use sentences for context. Sometimes sentences are way too long to make a good flashcard. In Japanese I am not yet at a level where I have a good feel for if I've changed a sentence too much, for example mistaking an intransitive verb for transitive, or misplacing a particle. Do these simplifications work, or do they need fixing? I will use the answers here as guidelines for future simplifications.

Original #1:

> つぎの日の夜明け、海鳥の群れがいくつも、大きな白い雲のようにかたまって、風に**しなう**森の木々の上空を流されていった。

Shortening #1:

> 森の木々が風に**しなった**。

Original #2:

> 両がわが、刈りこまれた高い**イチイ**の生け垣になっている。

Shortening #2:

> 両がわは刈りこまれた**イチイ**の生け垣がいる。

Original #3:

> 元気なく**尾**が垂れている犬

Shortening #3:

> 犬は**尾**が垂れている。

The one I feel most unsure about is the third sentence. It is also not only shorting, but turning a concept into a complete sentence, which I prefer to do. My first option was 犬が尾を垂れている but it sounds wrong to my ears and is probably a case of mistaking the transitivity of a verb.

Edit: I forgot to highlight the vocabulary each sentence is provided for. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

> つぎの日の夜明け、海鳥の群れがいくつも、大きな白い雲のようにかたまって、風にしなう森の木々の上空を流されていった。

### remove time

> 海鳥の群れがいくつも、大きな白い雲のようにかたまって、風にしなう森の木々の上空を流されていった。

### remove state representation

> 海鳥の群れがいくつも、森の木々の上空を流されていった。

### formatting

> 海鳥の群れが，森の上空を飛んでいた．

## 2, 3

I think theirs are very simplified.

If I had to say shortening is following.

### 2

> 両がわが、刈りこまれた高いイチイの生け垣になっている。

> 両側が、イチイの生け垣である。

### 3

> 元気なく尾が垂れている犬

> 尾が垂れている犬

Comment: Thank you. The third sentence comes from the Kenkyusha J-E dictionary. I prefer bilingual entries where I can find them, as they decrease the risk of misunderstanding. 元気なく尾が垂れている犬 is translated as 
"a dog with its tail flagging". I would like to turn it into a complete sentence, that is, a phrase that can be ended with a "。" symbol.

Comment: I think it is not strange without "。" because "元気なく尾が垂れている犬" is "state + noun". it is not sentence. "犬"→"尾が垂れている犬"